# Discord.js messaging errors

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been recently working on my second Discord.JS bot. I coded some basics and tested it. However, when I use the `.verify` command, it didn't make any reactions. Please help!

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const prefix = "."

client.on("ready", () => { console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`) })

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}verify`)) {
        message.channel.send('SUCCESFULLY VERIFIED');
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the error code to get better notifications. For more information about errors in Discord.js, see the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#how-to-diagnose-api-errors).

Comment: You should add the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent too, like `intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe after `message.channel.send('SUCCESFULLY VERIFIED')` put `.catch(console.error)`

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const prefix = "."

client.on("ready", () => { console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`) })

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}verify`)) {
        message.channel.send('SUCCESFULLY VERIFIED').catch(console.error)
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

actually we can't do anythink because you don't send the error

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add the GUILD_MESSAGES intent.
2. In discord.js v13 they changed client.on('message') to client.on('messageCreate').

[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message)